# Customer Account Data API - How to remove a cert

Tags: intuit-partner-platform

How do you remove a certificate that you've uploaded for a customer account data api app?  I have the option to add a new certificate and an option to change the certificate, but no option to delete.

I accidentally uploaded a cert to the wrong app and I don't want to leave it there.

Comment: Please add more detail about your problem. For more info see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Answer (score 0):

Your existing cert will be replaced with the newly uploaded one. So, you don't need to delete the cert.